# How to detect marked black regions inside largest Rectangle Contour?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I can detect largest contour the answer sheet (20 questions, each have 4 alternative)

After the draw largest contour, what shall I do? Divide matris the rectangle by 20x4 cell? Or find countour again but this time inside the rectangle? I dont know what I need. Just I want to get which is marked.

I looked at [this documant](http://www.academia.edu/6760034/COMPUTER_VISION_BASED_OMR_SHEET_EVALUATION_USING_OPENCV).

How to codding "image gridding and division"?

[image]

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        return findLargestRectangle(inputFrame.rgba());
    }


    private Mat findLargestRectangle(Mat original_image) {
        Mat imgSource = original_image;
        hierarchy = new Mat();

        //convert the image to black and white
        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        //convert the image to black and white does (8 bit)
        Imgproc.Canny(imgSource, imgSource, 50, 50);

        //apply gaussian blur to smoothen lines of dots
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new Size(5, 5), 5);

        //find the contours
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(imgSource, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        hierarchy.release();

        double maxArea = -1;
        int maxAreaIdx = -1;
        MatOfPoint temp_contour = contours.get(0); //the largest is at the index 0 for starting point
        MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        Mat largest_contour = contours.get(0);
        List<MatOfPoint> largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
            temp_contour = contours.get(idx);
            double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour);
            //compare this contour to the previous largest contour found
            if (contourarea > maxArea) {
                //check if this contour is a square
                MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f( temp_contour.toArray() );
                int contourSize = (int)temp_contour.total();
                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve, contourSize*0.05, true);
                if (approxCurve.total() == 4) {
                    maxArea = contourarea;
                    maxAreaIdx = idx;
                    largest_contours.add(temp_contour);
                    largest_contour = temp_contour;
                }
            }
        }
        MatOfPoint temp_largest = largest_contours.get(largest_contours.size()-1);
        largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        largest_contours.add(temp_largest);


        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);
        Imgproc.drawContours(imgSource, contours, maxAreaIdx, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
        Log.d(TAG, "Largers Contour:" + contours.get(maxAreaIdx).toString());


        return imgSource;
    }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I want to thank you @sturkmen for the his answer. I can read and find black regions now. Here the Android codes:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    Button btnTest = (Button) _view.findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(mediaStorageDir().getPath() + "/" + "test2.jpg");
            if (img.empty()) {
                Log.d("Fragment", "IMG EMPTY");
            }


            Mat gray = new Mat();
            Mat thresh = new Mat();

            //convert the image to black and white
            Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

            //convert the image to black and white does (8 bit)
            Imgproc.threshold(gray, thresh, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
            Mat temp = thresh.clone();
            //find the contours
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

            Mat corners = new Mat(4,1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            Imgproc.findContours(temp, contours,hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            hierarchy.release();

            for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++)
            {
                MatOfPoint contour = contours.get(idx);
                MatOfPoint2f contour_points = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
                RotatedRect minRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect( contour_points );
                Point[] rect_points = new Point[4];
                minRect.points( rect_points );
                if(minRect.size.height > img.width() / 2)
                {
                    List<Point> srcPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(4);
                    srcPoints.add(rect_points[2]);
                    srcPoints.add(rect_points[3]);
                    srcPoints.add(rect_points[0]);
                    srcPoints.add(rect_points[1]);

                    corners = Converters.vector_Point_to_Mat(
                            srcPoints, CvType.CV_32F);
                }

            }
            Imgproc.erode(thresh, thresh, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 10);
            Imgproc.dilate(thresh, thresh, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 5);
            Mat results = new Mat(1000,250,CvType.CV_8UC3);
            Mat quad = new Mat(1000,250,CvType.CV_8UC1);

            List<Point> dstPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(4);
            dstPoints.add(new Point(0, 0));
            dstPoints.add(new Point(1000, 0));
            dstPoints.add(new Point(1000, 250));
            dstPoints.add(new Point(0, 250));
            Mat quad_pts = Converters.vector_Point_to_Mat(
                    dstPoints, CvType.CV_32F);

            Mat transmtx = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(corners, quad_pts);
            Imgproc.warpPerspective( img, results, transmtx, new Size(1000,250));
            Imgproc.warpPerspective( thresh, quad, transmtx, new Size(1000,250));

            Imgproc.resize(quad,quad,new Size(20,5));

            Imgcodecs.imwrite("results.png",quad);

            //show image
            showImage(quad);

            //store image
            storeImage(quad);

        }

    });

    return _view;
}

public void showImage (Mat img) {
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sampleImageView);
    //Mat mRgba = new Mat();

    //mRgba = Utils.loadResource(MainAct.this, R.drawable.your_image,Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Bitmap img2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.cols(), img.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(img, img2);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(img2);
}

public File mediaStorageDir () {
    File _mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

    return _mediaStorageDir;
}

public void storeImage(Mat matImg) {

    Bitmap bitmapImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(matImg.cols(), matImg.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(matImg, bitmapImg);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    String mImageName="IMG_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir().getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);

    File pictureFile = mediaFile;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("FragmentMain", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("FragmentMain", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is my trial code as a sample.

i hope it will be helpful. ( i will add some explanation about the code later)

**Test Image** ( edited your image. having an empty and invalid double mark )

[image: image description]
<sub>(source: [opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14639435664447751.jpg))</sub>

**Result Image**

[image: image description]
<sub>(source: [opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14639682486508377.jpeg))</sub>

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    Mat img = imread(argv[1]);
    if(img.empty())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    Size dims(20,5); // this variable should be changed according input
    Mat gray,thresh;
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(gray, thresh, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV + THRESH_OTSU);

    Mat quad(img.size(), CV_8UC1); // should be improved
    Mat results(img.size(), CV_8UC3);

    vector<Point2f> quad_pts;
    quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
    quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, 0));
    quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, quad.rows));
    quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, quad.rows));

    vector<Point2f> corners;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    findContours(thresh.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        RotatedRect minRect = minAreaRect( Mat(contours[i]) );

        // rotated rectangle
        Point2f rect_points[4];
        minRect.points( rect_points );

        if(Rect(minRect.boundingRect()).width > img.cols / 2) // should be improved
            for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
            {
              Point2f pt = quad_pts[j];
              Point2f nearest_pt = rect_points[0];
              float dist = norm( pt - nearest_pt );
                for( int k = 1; k < 4; k++ )
                {
                 if( norm( pt - rect_points[k] ) < dist )
                 {
                   dist = norm( pt - rect_points[k] );
                   nearest_pt = rect_points[k];
                 }
                }
                corners.push_back( nearest_pt );
            }
    }

    erode(thresh,thresh,Mat(),Point(-1,-1), 10); // should be improved
    dilate(thresh,thresh,Mat(),Point(-1,-1), 5); // should be improved

    Mat transmtx = getPerspectiveTransform(corners, quad_pts);
    warpPerspective( img, results, transmtx, img.size()); // Create a Mat To Show results
    warpPerspective( thresh, quad, transmtx, img.size());

    resize(quad,quad,dims);

    for(int i = 0; i < quad.cols; i++)
    {
        String answer = "";

        answer += quad.at<uchar>(1,i) == 0 ? "" : "A";
        answer += quad.at<uchar>(2,i) == 0 ? "" : "B";
        answer += quad.at<uchar>(3,i) == 0 ? "" : "C";
        answer += quad.at<uchar>(4,i) == 0 ? "" : "D";

        if( answer.length()  > 1 ) answer = "X"; // Double mark
        int y = 0;
        if( answer == "A" ) y = results.rows / dims.height;
        if( answer == "B" ) y = results.rows / dims.height *2;
        if( answer == "C" ) y = results.rows / dims.height *3;
        if( answer == "D" ) y = results.rows / dims.height *4;
        if( answer == "" ) answer = "[-]";
        putText( results, answer, Point( 50* i + 15, 30 + y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, Scalar(0,0,255),2);

    }
    imshow( "results", results );
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

as a challenge to myself i tried to implement main part in JAVA ( a newcomer copy paste code )

```
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread("test.jpg");
Mat gray = new Mat();
Mat thresh = new Mat();

//convert the image to black and white
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

//convert the image to black and white does (8 bit)
Imgproc.threshold(gray, thresh, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
Mat temp = thresh.clone();
//find the contours
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

Mat corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Imgproc.findContours(temp, contours,hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
hierarchy.release();

for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++)
{
    MatOfPoint contour = contours.get(idx);
    MatOfPoint2f contour_points = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
    RotatedRect minRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect( contour_points );
    Point[] rect_points = new Point[4];
    minRect.points( rect_points );
    if(minRect.size.height > img.width() / 2)
    {
        List<Point> srcPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(4);
        srcPoints.add(rect_points[2]);
        srcPoints.add(rect_points[3]);
        srcPoints.add(rect_points[0]);
        srcPoints.add(rect_points[1]);

        corners = Converters.vector_Point_to_Mat(
                      srcPoints, CvType.CV_32F);
    }

}
Imgproc.erode(thresh, thresh, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 10);
Imgproc.dilate(thresh, thresh, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 5);
Mat results = new Mat(1000,250,CvType.CV_8UC3);
Mat quad = new Mat(1000,250,CvType.CV_8UC1);

List<Point> dstPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(4);
dstPoints.add(new Point(0, 0));
dstPoints.add(new Point(1000, 0));
dstPoints.add(new Point(1000, 250));
dstPoints.add(new Point(0, 250));
Mat quad_pts = Converters.vector_Point_to_Mat(
                   dstPoints, CvType.CV_32F);

Mat transmtx = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(corners, quad_pts);
Imgproc.warpPerspective( img, results, transmtx, new Size(1000,250));
Imgproc.warpPerspective( thresh, quad, transmtx, new Size(1000,250));

Imgproc.resize(quad,quad,new Size(20,5));

Imgcodecs.imwrite("results.png",quad);
```

here is the (20x5px) result image : [image: image description]

Comment: thank you very much. I'm going to try as soon as possible. @sturkmen

Answer (score 1):

I imrove @sturkmen' s code.

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="{your package name}.FragmentMain">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Test" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sampleImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
</framelayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

*Add this line for write permission.*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**FragmentMain.java**

**IMAGE FILE:** *Add Internal Storage/Android/Data/Your Package Folder/test.JPG*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    Button btnTest = (Button) _view.findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(mediaStorageDir().getPath() + "/" + "test.JPG");
            if (img.empty()) {
                Log.d("FragmentMain", "Empty Image");
            }


            Size dims = new Size (20,5);
            Mat gray = new Mat();
            Mat thresh = new Mat();

            //convert the image to black and white
            Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            storeImage(gray);

            //convert the image to black and white does (8 bit)
            Imgproc.threshold(gray, thresh, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

            storeImage(thresh);

            Mat temp = thresh.clone();
            //find the contours
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

            Mat corners = new Mat(4,1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            Imgproc.findContours(temp, contours,hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            hierarchy.release();

            for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++)
            {
                MatOfPoint contour = contours.get(idx);
                MatOfPoint2f contour_points = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
                RotatedRect minRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect( contour_points );
                Point[] rect_points = new Point[4];
                minRect.points( rect_points );
                if(minRect.size.height > img.width() / 2)
                {
                    List<Point> srcPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(4);
                    srcPoints.add(rect_points[2]);
                    srcPoints.add(rect_points[3]);
                    srcPoints.add(rect_points[0]);
                    srcPoints.add(rect_points[1]);

                    corners = Converters.vector_Point_to_Mat(
                            srcPoints, CvType.CV_32F);
                }

            }
            Imgproc.erode(thresh, thresh, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 10);

            storeImage(thresh);
            Imgproc.dilate(thresh, thresh, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 5);

            storeImage(thresh);

            Mat results = new Mat(1000,250,CvType.CV_8UC3);
            Mat quad = new Mat(1000,250,CvType.CV_8UC1);

            List<Point> dstPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(4);
            dstPoints.add(new Point(0, 0));
            dstPoints.add(new Point(1000, 0));
            dstPoints.add(new Point(1000, 250));
            dstPoints.add(new Point(0, 250));
            Mat quad_pts = Converters.vector_Point_to_Mat(
                    dstPoints, CvType.CV_32F);

            Mat transmtx = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(corners, quad_pts);
            Imgproc.warpPerspective( img, results, transmtx, new Size(1000,250));
            Imgproc.warpPerspective( thresh, quad, transmtx, new Size(1000,250));

            Imgproc.resize(quad, quad, new Size(20,5));

            Imgcodecs.imwrite("results.png",quad);

            //store image
            storeImage(quad);

            //show image
            showImage(quad);


            System.out.println( quad.dump() );

            for(int i = 0; i < quad.cols(); i++)
            {
                int size = (int) (quad.total() * quad.channels());
                byte[] tmp = new byte[size];

                String answer = "";
                double[] d = new double[0];
                d = quad.get(1, i);
                answer += d[0] == 0 ? "" : "A";
                d = quad.get(2, i);
                answer += d[0] == 0 ? "" : "B";
                d = quad.get(3, i);
                answer += d[0] == 0 ? "" : "C";
                d = quad.get(4, i);
                answer += d[0] == 0 ? "" : "D";

                if( answer.length()  > 1 ) answer = "X"; // Double mark
                int y = 0;
                if( answer.equals("A")) y = results.rows() / (int) dims.height;
                if( answer.equals("B")) y = results.rows() / (int) dims.height *2;
                if( answer.equals("C")) y = results.rows() / (int) dims.height *3;
                if( answer.equals("D")) y = results.rows() / (int) dims.height *4;
                if( answer == "" ) answer = "[-]";
                Imgproc.putText( results, answer, new Point( 50* i + 15, 30 + y), Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, new Scalar(0,0,255),2);

            }


            //store image
            storeImage(results);

            //show image
            showImage(results);

        }

    });
public void showImage (Mat img) {
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sampleImageView);
    //Mat mRgba = new Mat();

    //mRgba = Utils.loadResource(MainAct.this, R.drawable.your_image,Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Bitmap img2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.cols(), img.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(img, img2);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(img2);
}

public File mediaStorageDir () {
    File _mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

    return _mediaStorageDir;
}

public void storeImage(Mat matImg) {

    Bitmap bitmapImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(matImg.cols(), matImg.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(matImg, bitmapImg);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    String mImageName="IMG_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir().getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);

    File pictureFile = mediaFile;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("FragmentMain", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("FragmentMain", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that i updated c++ code but could not update JAVA code. this code need to be updated.